# How do you install a Ruby on Rails apps on Windows/IIS?

Tags: ruby, iis-7, windows-server-2008, redmine

I'm trying to get Redmine working on Windows/IIS 7.  I've found several walkthroughs online, but none of them work on my Windows Server 2008 R2 box.  I got a simple app (create app, no customization) to get as far as RoR error, but Redmine itself shows a 500 error (ruby.exe exited unexpectedly).  I installed sqlite since some guides mention that, though Redmine uses MySQL by default.  I started with the Bitnami installer and tried to customize for IIS, RorIIS, FastCGI, lots of things that look like they should work, but this problem is killing me.

If I run ruby.exe from the command line, passing it the path to the dispath.fcgi file I get an error: "The procedure entry point SetMagickMemoryMethods could not be located in the dynamic link library CORE_RL_magick_.dll".  I had to install the rmagick gem myself which seemed strange since everything worked perfectly under Apache.  I really thought it would be a smooth cut-over since it's up and running already and just changing web server.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried a lot to install Redmine on Windows environment under IIS. There's very little (or none) documentation about it. Lost many days on this. In the end, I decided to stick to the **Bitnami** stack of Redmine. The only caveat is that we had to use another port (8080, in our case), that's it. I gave up the idea of integrating Redmine/RoR with IIS and never looked back. Everything is working great in production now and everyone is happy about it around here.

Sorry I can't give a better answer than that, I'm just sharing some recent experience. I was obsessed about integrating RoR/ISS until I realized it was not a real requirement, it was just something I stuck into my mind. Think about it.

Comment: That's what I ended up deciding.  Unfortunately, we put lots of time into IIS.  That's how it's deployed now, but it was more trouble than it was worth.  Thanks for the response!